# How to call Azure OpenAI add your data API

Tags: azure, azure-openai

An error occurred when I made the api call.
I am at a loss as to the cause. Does anyone know what the problem is?

The following is the response from the API call.

```
{"error": {"requestid": "c4f88e85-98f0-46e0-8ffa-xxxxxxxxxxxx", "code": 400, "message": "Invalid JSON in request body"}}
```

The following is the content of the API call.

```
api_base="https://test_api.openai.azure.com/"
api_key="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
deployment_id="gpt-4-32k-test"
search_endpoint="https://test_api.search.windows.net"
search_key="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
search_index="index_name"
curl -i -X POST $api_base/openai/deployments/$deployment_id/extensions/chat/completions?api-version=2023-08-01-preview \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -H "api-key: $api_key" \
  -d \
  '
  {
  "dataSources": [
    {
      "type": "AzureCognitiveSearch",
      "parameters": {
        "endpoint": "'$search_endpoint'",
        "key": "'$search_key'",
        "indexName": "'$search_index'"
      }
    }
  ],
  "messages": [{"role":"system","content":"You are an AI assistant that helps people find information."}],
}
  '
```

I think the json format and parameter information is correct,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you still need to provide more parameters, like the Fields binding, and also to add at least one "user" message, not just the system prompt. Take a look to this sample I created using that API from an SPFx webpart:
https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/blob/main/samples/react-azure-openai-connector/src/webparts/ourHotelsFinder/models/CompletionsRequestBuilder.ts

Let me know if it helps.
Cheers.

Comment: I added role: user as you taught me and it works fine! (even without system)
Thanks for your help!

"messages": [{"role":"user","content":"add role:user contents"}],

Comment: glad it worked! have fun with Azure Open AI :)